# Unable to make stairs larger in width while keeping the same pattern

Tags: transforms

I have downloaded some stairs block and for my project I need to modify them. I need to make them wider, but keep the shape of the steps. When I try that, it makes my stair steps larger in width but it completely destroys the shape.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

[File of Stairs](https://gofile.io/d/HhaSwz)

Here you can see the left and right posts of the stair block used to attach the steps. The bottom step is the original size. The step selected I've tried to scale.

[image: screenshot of the stairs]

Comment: It seems you can't scale the block in X direction without scaling also the grid (the pattern ?). To make it larger, you probably have to cut it in 3 parts (left, middle, right). Then you translate the right part and you duplicate the middle part as many time as required to fill the gap.

Comment: @StefLAncien you're right. The unselected stair step is the original and the selected stair step is a try to resize it in X direction. It gets stretched because it's one mesh part. (The blend file is accessible now.)

Comment: From the Blender file, it appears that instead of scaling, in Edit Mode, you can select all the faces of the right hand side of the stair step, then move these in X direction until the right post. The "bars" will be elongated. After that, you have to duplicate the small cylinders. Using an Array modifier might greatly simplify the task. Just ask if you need a step by step answer with pictures.